# Heroku app name change and mLab mongodDB timout

Tags: heroku, mlab

My situation: I wanted to change my app name on heroku. I have done so with Heroku CLI and get confirmation that change was success. However, after this change I've started to receive a weird errors on mLab.

[image]

From my panel I can see that there is no user to connect to DB, but when I create one, it is deleted after relogin and get same error. Did anybaody face such a problem? Did you manage to find a solution?

I've checked status page and there were no issues. What's more I tried to contact support, but without any response (it's only sandbox, so I't quite obvious that my question will be replied last.....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacting support helped. But I have got no info what was wrong.